# Is spat the correct flag to use in my ogr2ogr command?

Tags: postgresql, geojson, ogr2ogr

I have an `ogr2ogr` command that I'm using to convert part of a Postgres database to a Geojson. I ingested all of Canada in my database and to start, I want to grab all of the buildings in the Toronto area for my first Geojson.

I've tried using `spat` in my command, but I don't get any features back. Is `spat` the correct flag or do I need to be using another one?

Command:

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" ./toronto-buildings.geojson -t_srs 'EPSG:4326' PG:"host=localhost port=5432 user='MY USER NAME' dbname='gis'" -spat -79.9352, 43.4968, -79.1414, 43.9124 -sql 'SELECT way, "building" AS type FROM planet_osm_polygon ORDER BY ST_YMin(ST_Envelope(way)) DESC' -progress
```

Output:

```
{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "crs":{
      "type":"name",
      "properties":{
         "name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
      }
   },
   "features":[

   ]
}
```